# How to change method body with plugin?

Tags: magento2

How can I add new IF statement to `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler::check()` body with a plugin? I don't want to override it like in Magento 1.

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-use-plugins/  see this link to get idea about plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this you should use Around Plugin :

Here are the steps :

1. Define the plugin in *[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/etc/di.xml*
2. Create a Plugin in
   *[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Plugin/[Plugin_Class].php*

example:

1. step 1 :

**etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State">
    <plugin name="[Plugin_Name]" type="[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Plugin/[Plugin_Class]"/>
</type>
```

2. Step 2: 
   **Vendor_Name/Module_Name/Plugin/[Plugin_Class].php**

```
class [Plugin_Class]
{ 
   public function aroundCheck(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        // this will vary depending on your requirement.
        if ([your condition]) {
           return $proceed($subject);  
        }
        return;    
    }


}
```